# multiplatform atomic increment

Tags: c++, boost, synchronization, atomic, multiplatform

Until `std::atomic` is available, what is the multiplatform (windows & linux) way of atomically increment a variable ?

I am currently use `boost::detail::atomic_count` but it's in `boost::detail` namespace and I don't know if it's safe to use.

Comment: Have you looked at the currently-under-review [Boost.Atomic](http://www.chaoticmind.net/~hcb/projects/boost.atomic/doc/index.html) library?

Comment: `std::atomic` is already available. No?

Comment: MSVC and GCC both have std::atomic support now. There's also http://www.stdthread.co.uk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A **multiplatform**, but compiler specific way is to use GCC's `__sync_fetch_and_add`.

Or define such a function yourself with a bit of conditional compilation:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#define atomic_inc(ptr) __sync_fetch_and_add ((ptr), 1)
#elif defined (_WIN32)
#define atomic_inc(ptr) InterlockedIncrement ((ptr))
#else
#error "Need some more porting work here"
#endif
```

Comment: __sync_fetch_and_add and MSVC InterlockedIncrement are not equivalent in their return types. __sync_fetch_and_add returns the *previous* value of ptr and InterlockedIncrement returns the resulting value of the incremented ptr. What you need to use is "__sync_add_and_fetch" to be equivalent/interchangeable.

Comment: Additionally, `InterlockedIncrement` is only for 32-bit values.

Answer (score 0):

Use *InterlockedExchangeAdd* instead of *InterlockedIncrement* - it full analogue, with *__sync_fetch_and_add*;

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#define atomic_inc(ptr) __sync_fetch_and_add ((ptr), 1)
#elif defined (_WIN32)
#define atomic_inc(ptr) InterlockedExchangeAdd ((ptr), 1)
#else
#error "Need some more porting work here"
#endif
```

You can find proven analogs of msvc/gcc calls [here](https://github.com/mozilla/positron/blob/master/js/src/jit/x86-shared/AtomicOperations-x86-shared.h) (x86)